# Why would IntelliJ code coverage not show all coverage?

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

I have unit tests that I am certain covers a block of Java code. For example, if I run the debugger during unit testing, I can step right through that code. And the results I get can only be gotten from executing that code.

However, the IntelliJ native code coverage tool (even in Trace mode) gives  most of those statements in that block a pink color coding. The coloration does not even seem to make sense, since some green statements are preceded by pink statements that MUST have been executed first.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior, and hopefully how to fix it?

Comment: What type of the project do you have?

Comment: I am using Java, and the unit test frameworks used are EasyMock and TestNG.